# Open same website in a 2nd tab while 1st tab is still loading

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have PHP script that takes 60s to execute. I open it in one tab in Chrome.
I want to open the same script in a 2nd tab but it won't run until the 1st tab has finished execution. Actually, I cannot access the entire website until the script has finished execution.

On the other hand, I can open the same script/website and run it in Firefox or other browsers, though it runs on Chrome. I want to be able to run multiple instances of that script from the same browser.

Is there a server setting? How can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: A script should not exede 4 seconds, if this is a big process it should be in a job queue or try to optimize your code. Please provide the piece of code

Comment: That depends on the application. I have apps that run 5-6 minutes. It handles encoding jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such behaviour is usually due to PHP session locking. While the first script is running, it locks the session and therefore the second script has to wait for it to unlock.

To fix this, close the session before starting the long process.

```
session_write_close();
// now run your slow code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will test this!